# "apache2ctl command not found" appears when invoking apache2ctl

Tags: apache-2.2

I am running Apache 2.4.6 on my CentOS 6.4 server.

Having some trouble with rewrite...so was trying to check loaded modules

```
apache2ctl -M
```

But that returns

```
apache2ctl command not found
```

So I tried

```
which apache2ctl
```

and I get

```
no apache2ctl in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

I am sure apache is installed and running.

How do I find apache2ctl/ check loaded modules now?

Answer (score 4):

How did you install Apache?  2.4 isn't what you'll get from a package install on CentOS 6.

If you installed from source or a third party package, you'll probably need to do some manual fiddling to get the control script in the right place if it's not there already.

Comment: Yup, compiled from source.

Comment: @OC2PS Then, where did you configure it to put the binaries?  Look for `apachectl` there.  Then symlink to it from one of the `bin` directories, or add it to your `$PATH`.